# count every time a number switches in a list of sublists [python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

If I have a list that looks something like this

```
my-list = [[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

and if I want to count every time the elements change values. For example, if we define a variable called `counter`,

```
counter = 0
```

and every time each element of the sublist changes into something different (either from 1-->0 or 0-->1), `counter` increments.

If we look at `my-list` from above, the first and second element from `my-list[0]` goes from `1` to `0`, so `counter` increments +1. The second and third element of `my-list[0]` is `0` and `0`, and since the values didn't change, the increment of `counter` doesn't happen. But the third and forth element of `my-list[0]` goes from `0` to `1`, so another increment happens.

And then we start this over in the second sublist, `my-list[1]`. The first and second values of `my-list[1]` are different (changes from `1` to `0`), so `counter` is incremented for the third time. If we look at the final result,

```
print(counter)
>>> 3
```

`3`, is the answer I'm looking for `my-list`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the absolute value of the difference

```
sum(abs(l[i]-l[i+1]) for l in my_list for i in range(len(l)-1))
```

or if they don't consist of only `1s` and `0s`

```
sum(1 if l[i] != l[i+1] else 0  for l in my_list for i in range(len(l)-1))
```

Comment: I don't think differences between the end of a sublist and the start of the next one should be counted.

Comment: but that introduces an unwanted increment if the list is something like
`my-list = [[1,0,0,1],[0,1]]`
the unwanted increment is between `my-list[0][3]` and `my-list[1][0]`

Comment: updated in order not to consider the end of a sublist and the start of the next one